# Rails with Wicked gem. Data will not update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-persistence, wicked-gem

I am using the Wicked gem to create an object in multiple steps. Everything seemed to be working fine until I realized that the data was not saving. I noticed it was not saving whenever `url: wizard_path` was present in the form builder. When that is not there, the data saves just fine, no matter which step I am on. This is what my controller for the object builder looks like:

```
class Bids::BuildController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :intro, :problems, :solutions, :pricing

  def show
    @bid = Bid.find(params[:bid_id])
    render_wizard
  end

  def create
    @bid = Bid.new(bid_params)
    redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first, :bid_id => @bid.id)
  end

  def update
    @bid = Bid.find(params[:bid_id])
    params[:bid][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
    @bid.attributes = params[:bid].permit(:bid_attribute)
    render_wizard @bid
  end

  # GET /bids/new
  def new
    @bid = Bid.new
    redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first, :bid_id => @bid.id)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you check your log for errors? My guess is you have to white list the parameters. CHeck your log for forbidden attribute error

Comment: @deep I did get an error in the logs. Unpermitted parameters. What is whitelisting parameters?

Comment: @deep In my build controller, I do have this .permit(:fields) for my bid model. But do I need this in the above controller (bids/build_controller.rb)?

Comment: Add a private method like def bid_params and inside the method add params.require(:bid).permit(:status, :attribute_1, :atribute_2). Note you need to permit all the attributes you are getting through the form and then simply use @bid.attributes = bid_params

Comment: Read more about strong parameters here http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in your comment that you are permitting params in the bid controller. Add them to your build controller. Since you are building your object in this controller, it needs to have access to the permitted params.

Add:

```
def build_params
  params.require(:bid).permit(:param_1,:param_2,:param_3,:etc)
end
```

to your `bids/build_controller.rb`